# Solving Inequality Relation:

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

I have this inequality that I deduce from the problem:

$$
\frac{3}{a+b} < \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}\right) 
$$

For the sake of problem: assuming $a,b > 0$ and $a \neq b$. How do I solve for the relation? (I was thinking this relates to AM - GM inequality).

Comment: Do you want to prove this inequality holds for any $a,b> 0$ (it's not true)? Or do you find all $a,b>0$ such that the inequality is true?

Comment: I want to have the relation $a > c \cdot b$ for some constant $c$.

Answer (score 2):

We have:

$$0<\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}-\frac{6}{a+b}=\frac{a^2-4ab+b^2}{ab(a+b)}$$

To hold, we need that $a^2-4ab+b^2>0$. Dividing by $b^2$ we get the following

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}-4\frac{a}{b}+1>0$$

Let $t = \dfrac{a}{b}$. Substituting we get the following second degree inequality $\quad t^2-4t+1 > 0 \quad$ which is solved when $t < 2-\sqrt{3}$ or $t > 2+\sqrt{3}$.

In conclusion the two possible solutions are: $$a < (2-\sqrt{3})b \\ a>(2+\sqrt{3})b$$

Comment: I really appreciate. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Regarding Gabrielek's edit, first of all thanks, it looks better than before. I just have one question. English is not my native language. However, in my language there is a difference between inequality (something you prove because direction is known) and inequation (something you solve because the direction is not known, it's known only that the quantities are different). Isn't inequation a more suitable term here than inequality?

Comment: Thank you for your approval. Neither for me enghlish is my first language so I'll be honest: I've always used "inequality" not caring about the existance of the word  ineqution... it is more... fluid. Anyway I don't see such a big difference